# time series model with low pacf

Tags: r, time-series, lm, acf-pacf

I have data on annual temperatures covering 21 years, measured at one single loaction. I want to build a regressive model to find out whether there was a significant warming during that time span. I am working in R.

This my data:

```
> summer.temperatures
   year temperature
1  1996    10.99241
2  1997    11.83630
3  1998    11.99259
4  1999    12.41907
5  2000    12.06093
6  2001    12.27000
7  2002    11.79556
8  2003    13.32352
9  2004    12.10741
10 2005    11.98704
11 2006    12.89407
12 2007    11.24778
13 2008    11.85759
14 2009    12.51148
15 2010    11.29870
16 2011    12.35389
17 2012    12.33648
18 2013    12.24463
19 2014    12.31481
20 2015    12.73481
21 2016    12.43167

> plot(summer.temperatures)
```

[image]

The pacf values turned out to be rather low, so there is no pattern of previous years predicting the current year - am I right?
Here is the pacf - plot:

```
> pacf (summer.temperatures $ temperature)
```

[image]

My question is: based on these findings, how can I test whether there has been a significant warming over the 21 observed years? Normally, in time series I cannot use linear models, beacuse of the non-independence of the measurments. However, with such low pacf values, is it reasonable to state that the measurements indeed ARE independent? Or is there another way to deal with such a time series?

Comment: You are right when you say that low ACF/PACF tells you that you cannot LINEARLY predict year 2 from year 1. However notice that this is just a necessary but not sufficient condition for independence. Indeed, it might be that if you square the observations, you find that the square of year 2 depends on the square of year 1.

Comment: The best thing in general is to use MLE for estimation. However here it seems that you do not have much to estimate because the PACF suggests you have a non-persistent process. At least when it comes to linear relationships. But if I see correctly you have VERY FEW data, so how are you building that PACF? With 20 observations? It is a very noisy estimate in that case, with a lot of standard error, which may distort the test with the bands that you see from the PACF. I think it would be better to gather some additional data..

Comment: For my purpose, I just need to know whether there was a significant warming from 1996 to 2016. I could collect some additional data points to build the PACF. However, the available data is restricted because temperatures have not been measured for centuries at that specific location.

Comment: could this be a good model for my purpose: `library (nlme)` | 
`mod.1 <- gls (temperature ~ year , 
              data = summer.temperatures, 
              correlation = corAR1(form = ~ year ))` ?

Comment: I think that you should be using corARMA because the data seem to have a very low persistence so it is very unlikely you will find an AR significant structure. It is more likely that in the best scenario you will find a low persistence modeled via MA. So if we use corARMA you are allowing for MA correlation. However, if your PACF is the one above, I think you will find non-significant coefficients even for a MA. But you can try of course. Notice also that for your particular case where you want to evaluate whether the next year temp is higher than current year, it will make sense to look..

Comment: .. look also at the significance and sign of the intercept here..

Comment: In easy words: with `gls (... correlation = corARMA (...))`, I can fit a linear model that allows for dependence of the measurments (AR meaning that each year is related to the previous year(s), MA meaning that the error of the prediction is related to the error of the prediction of the previous year(s))?

And what can the intercept tell me?
I am sorry for the large amount of questions - time series seem to be a rather complex issue...

Comment: MA means that the next year Value is related to the error of this year. The intercept is something to be added to the ARMA for each forecast of the next year, so given the intercept a, then a will increase the forecast for each year if positive or will decrease it if negative. It is part of the typical Arma, so an Arma with no intercept can be viewed as an Arma with intercept set to 0.

Comment: thank you so much. I think, I did understand a lot now. However, as I deal with longterm means of temperature, there is no logic basis for me to assume that the error of the prediction of one year is related to the error of the prediction of the next year. On the other hand, there might be a relation between the temperatures of two years - if december is rather cold, also january might be cold (and vice versa). From this perspective, I'd go for a AR1 model - even if the results are not significiant, which is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: I got your point. But for the sake of precision, I invite you to pay attention to the following, just to avoid mistakes: this is very important. An AR can be represented an infinite sum of MA terms. Which means that a MA(1) (for example) is just a term in the sum of MAs which is implicitly embedded into the AR(1). This makes a MA(1) a very short-memory version of an AR(1). Ok, it was just to remark it, in order to allow you to understand the difference between the two. If you google “AR infinite MA representation” or similar, you will find plenty of materials on the point